# AngularJS, ng-grid won't load data when using setTimeout() and pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, settimeout, ng-grid

I'm trying to use Ng-Grid with pagination option. I am able to display data in grid, format them, etc.

My controller:
http://pastebin.com/mnHE0rYq

The problem appears when I am trying to configure pagination. When using code like below, no data is rendered in table, but I know `$scope.myData` has data loaded (checked variable in console).

When I comment out `$timeout` function in `$scope.getPagedDataAsync` function ( I also tried `setTimeout()` - the same behaviour) I can see data in grid, but grid is not reloading after clicking next/previous page. Also, I noticed that `$scope.$apply()` is never called.

My Ng-Grid version is 2.0.11 and AngularJS is 1.2.16.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone face the same issue, the problem was really trivial and appears in HTML line (I didn't add this line to post, but I couldn't imagine there might be any problem):

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
```

I found out ng-controller can't be in the same tag with ng-grid.